# Display php variable in real-time

Tags: php

I have a php code which reads a text file with email addresses and sends each email using a loop. How can I display, in real-time, the status of each email sent from within the loop? Currently, I can only write to a log file, which can only be accessed once the php code has completed execution.

Comment: Where do you want to see the output? Using `tail -f` on the log file, in the console or in the browser?

Comment: I am assuming this is a PHP CLI script and not something you are running from the browser. Is that right?

Comment: when i hit the 'send' button the form page just sits there until all emails sent...thereafter displays my echo statements

Comment: yes its a php script with an html form

Comment: I need the output to display either in the current window or a new window.

Answer (score 0):

Flush the output if you want to echo to browser.

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.flush.php
```

> Flushes the system write buffers of PHP and whatever backend PHP is using (CGI, a web server, etc). This attempts to push current output all the way to the browser with a few caveats.

```
<?php
  for ($i=0; $i<10;$i++){
      echo $i."<br>";
      flush();
      ob_flush();
      sleep(1);
   }
```

Comment: the flush/sleep method does not work. the script still wiats for end of execution before displaying anything...is javascript/ajax the only solution??

Comment: Try ob_flush(), you may have implicit buffering.

Comment: @rubin edited the code , try it with the ob_flush now

Comment: sorry 4 delay..tried it..ob_flush() does not work..all echos show up after all emails sent ie when script completes execution. so if i'm sending 1000 emails the form page just sits there waiting for the script to complete.

Comment: @M.Alnashm..new here trying to find out how to post long code

Comment: @rubin post only the relevant parts, your loop probably.

Comment: // Send the message
if ($mailer->send($message)) {

$message = "".date("H:i:s").": Message Sent To <strong>\"".$receiver."\"</strong> <br>";
   writelog('b');
    
   $counter = $counter + 1;
    } else {
    echo 'Configuration Error.. :(';
    }
} 
            else 
                {
                $message = "<br>E-Mail Address <strong>\"".$receiver."\"</strong> is Invalid !<br>";
                writelog('b');
                }
                }

        // Delay before next send
        usleep($wait_time * 1000000);
         }
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);

Comment: @rubin are you by any chance using php-fpm?

Comment: @M.Alnashm..my script is hosted at SmarterASP.net. I have set the host to PHP 5.6. In addition, I am developing locally using Binami WampStack 5.6